# iOS wrong resolution when building to phone

Tags: ios, iphone, resolution, aspect-ratio

When I'm building my app after submitting a build I'm getting the wrong resolution when building on to my iPhone 6s its coming up with iPhone 4 aspect ratio. Any ideas what it could be?

It used to work fine when i was just developing the app

Comment: There's probably a problem in your splash screen. Are you using a media asset or a xib for designing your splash screen?

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't included iPhone 6s splash screen, works now